# Using complex where conditions in zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework

I have a static function in which I am passing some variables from the controller, In the function, I am doing some DB table joins and some other queries, the values I am passing is getting from the filters, If I am not selecting any filters I will get null values.

```
public static function Myfunction($var1,$var2,$var3)
{
 ...some database queries..
->joinLeft(some conditions)  
->joinLeft(some conditions)
->where('table1.val1 = ?',$var1)
->where('table2.val2 = ?', $var2)
->where('table3.val3 =?' ,$var3);

 return $data
}
```

Here If the values I am passing is null then I don't need to check the first condition, similarly in the case of 2nd and 3rd if the value is null then I don't need to check any conditions and have to fetch the whole value from the DB as per the query, somebody, please help me how to do that in Zend?

Answer (score 0):

I use a php Closure for this case to encapsulate the condition-checking as follows:

```
public static function Myfunction($var1,$var2,$var3)
{
    return $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use ($var1, $var2, $var3) {
            ...some database queries..
            $select->joinLeft(some conditions)  
            $select->joinLeft(some conditions);

            if (!empty($var1)) {
                    $select->where('table1.val1 = ?',$var1);
            }

            if (!empty($var2)) {
                    $select->where('table2.val2 = ?', $var2);
            }

            if (!empty($var3)) {
                    $select->where('table3.val3 =?' ,$var3);
            }
    });
}
```